# Custom comparator (ordering) as a (multi)map ordering parameter?

Tags: c++, comparator

My question is in many ways similar to this one: [Pass a custom comparator through a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10245728/884412), but I tried the solution proposed there, and could not get it to work.

In a nutshell, I have a method that keeps several sorted structures and performs several comparisons, always on elements of type `int`, **all using the same ordering**. The ordering is **determined when the method is called**.

The **intended call** would look something like: `myFunction(std::greater<int>());`

First, I tried declaring function as: `void myFunction(binary_operator<int, int, bool> order);` but, as per [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2568016/884412), `binary_function` is not suited to act as a base class in function calls.

Finally, **I tried** the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10245821/884412) (and many other sites), which suggested **using templates**. But, I still can not get my code to compile.

The minimal non-working example:

```
template <typename Comparator> 
void myFunction(Comparator order){

  if (order(1,2)){
      // some stuff
      // COMPILES OK
  }

  std::vector <int> vecToSort;
  // ... initialize
  std::sort(vecToSort.begin(), vecToSort.end(), order); // works
  // COMPILES OK

  std::multimap <int, int, order > boundary;
  // STARTS KICKING, SCREAMING AND SHOUTHING
}
```

and the compile error I get:

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template class std::multimap’
>   error:   expected a type, got ‘order’

I figured the same trick should work for both. It does not. (edit: I can see the `type`/`object` problem now)

*Can somebody please explain what is happening here and **how to get the*** **`multimap`** ***to use the ordering passed as the function argument?***

PS: I am not using boost for this project.

Comment: the error is very clear, order is a object not a type, thus cannot be pass into template parameter.

Comment: `std::multimap` needs a **type** as template parameter, and you are using an object.

Comment: okay, I see the type/object problem. But, that's just answering *why* I'm getting the error, not how to use my desired ordering (passed as a function parameter) to order my structures, including `multimap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be declared as follows:

```
std::multimap <int, int, Comparator> boundary(order);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

As the comments say, you need to provide a `type` not an `object`. These docs for [Construct multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/multimap/) give some examples.

Comment: okay, I see the problem with type / object. But, like this, which exact ordering will the elements in the `multimap` have? How to achieve that they be ordered by whatever is passed as function parameter in function call?

Comment: @penelope Apologies for the typo, I just fixed it.

Comment: @penelope Just by instantiating as shown above, passing `order` as constructor parameter. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Comparator` and `order` in this form:

```
std::multimap <int, int, Comparator> boundary (order);
```

First pass the compare type inside `<>` and then pass the compare object in constructor.